# access my backend node.js only from my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, server, whitelist

I wanted to know how I can do that only my android application, developed with native react, can access my API node js. So my server will be accessible only from my site, using a simple whitelist of domains, and from my app

Comment: you can't. You can never trust the client

Comment: @Jonas Wilms
The purpose of my app is to archive the user's positions. If you do not protect the API, anyone could make a simple HTTP request and "teleport" randomly around the world. Is there a way to verify the position?

Comment: You need to authenticate your user.. As stated by Jonas - never trust the client. But you can give elevated privileges to authenticated users, using API tokes etc. https://jwt.io/  <-- is your friend.

Comment: No, there is no way to ensure that the API requests are only done by your app, and there is also no way of making sure that the position sent is the clients actual position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to guarantee this. A client controls everything that happens on client side. If an application contains protection mechanisms against client interference, it can be reverse-engineered.

A way to protect unauthorized clients from connecting to the backend is make backend requests with API key that is transmitted as encrypted (hashed) string and verified on server side. Abused API keys need to be blacklisted.

Since hashed keys can be extracted from API requests, a way to make this more complicated is to make hashed API key dependent on specific requests, e.g.:

```
fetchData(url + '&api_key_hash=' + md5(SALT + url + SECRET_API_KEY))
```

`api_key_hash` still can be verified on server side but is useless for a client who wants to get unauthorized access to backend API. The only way for a client is to get `SECRET_API_KEY`.

Since client application can be reverse-engineered to get unencrypted API key, a way to make reverse engineering more complicated is to not store the key as plain string and obfuscate the application.

Note that while these measures don't guarantee that the application won't be reverse-engineered to extract API key, obfuscation can complicate things for application developer, e.g. debugging and analyzing crash reports. To my knowledge, reverse engineering of React Native application that doesn't make use of any protection besides JS obfuscation is trivial.

Comment: Is it better to store the `SECRET_API_KEY` and `SALT` inside `.env` file, so that, it can be reusable?

Comment: It's the same for any app config, it can be provided either at build time through env vars, or at runtime through backend request. Depends on your case if you ever expect these vars to be changed